# Surface Pro 3 suddenly will not boot from USB

Tags: usb-flash-drive, uefi, microsoft-surface-pro

I created a bootable Ubuntu 22.04 USB stick and successfully booted from it on a Surface Pro 3. I successfully "tried" ubuntu on the Surface Pro, and then decided to go ahead and install. I got as far as the custom partition screen, toggled a few things to remind me of the process, and decided to wait until later to go through with it. I clicked "back" or "quit" to abort the process at that point. I did not actually go through with any re-partitioning.

But thereafter, I'm unable to boot from the USB. I tried a new USB stick, re-flashed both sticks with both ubuntu and xubuntu several times, and tried all the different ways to boot off of the USB, including disabling secure boot and quick restart. The machine boots to Windows 10 still just fine, but if I remove all other boot sources in the Bios/UEFI so that USB is the only option, it just hangs on boot. The contents of the sticks look find when inspecting via File Explorer

What could I have broken with the aborted install? More importantly, how might I correct this?

Comment: Try to Reset the BIOS. Be ready to redo any setting that you changed in the BIOS.

Comment: Finally reporting back -- I tried every kind of reset I could find, with no joy. BUT I tried a Hail Mary and flashed Mint onto a USB instead of X/ubuntu, and that worked on the first try. I don't understand why, but I took the win.

Comment: I suggest that you post an answer with the details for future users.

Comment: @harrymc I don't really feel that this qualifies as an answer to the original problem, it's just a Plan B that happened to work for some inexplicable reason. I didn't _intend_ to become a Mint user. I thought the comment would suffice for future users, but if you believe it qualifies, I'll promote it as an answer.

Comment: An answer reporting back is better than no answer in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

An unintended solution to the problem for anybody who may be suffering the same way...

I tried every kind of reset I could find per comment/reply to the question, with no joy.

BUT I tried flashing Mint onto a USB instead of X/ubuntu, and that worked on the first try. I don't understand why -- I used one of the same sticks that failed with X/ubuntu.

Comment: The only reason is the first you tried was improperly made. Possible causes: Corrupt ISO, corruption while writing, ...

Comment: @ChanganAuto Nope. As explained, the USB stick _did_ work initially. That same stick subsequently did not. And it's hard to believe that _every_ subsequent re-write of both Ubuntu and Xubuntu (the same iso download) was corrupted, and suddenly a flashing with Mint was not corrupted. I don't accept the assertion at all.

Comment: So, the first one was good then it wasn't -> Corrupted while in use, it happens more often then we like. Then you "burned" Xubuntu that either failed or the ISO itself was corrupt or a quick of the tool used. BTW, how exactly are you making the installation/live media, using what method/tool...